# Peer authentication failed for user in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, authentication

I am trying to run some postgresql commands through a fabric script. When I execute the script I get:

```
out: psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "sparc2"
```

This is how my pg_hba.conf file looks like:

```
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#local   replication     postgres                                peer
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            md5
#host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 md5
# added
local   sparc2          sparc2                                  md5
host    sparc2          sparc2           127.0.0.1/32           md5
host    sparc2          sparc2           10.0.2.2/32            md5
host    all             all              all                    password
```

I have also modified the postgresql.conf file with adding this line:

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

After applying the changes I restarted postgresql. But the error is still the same.

Comment: Have you actually added the user (with `CREATE USER` or an equivalent method)?

Comment: The user was created through an ansible script: - name: "Grant All Privileges to {{ DB_USER }}"
  become: yes
  become_user: postgres
  postgresql_privs:
    db: "{{ DB_NAME }}"
    role: "{{ DB_USER }}"
    privs: ALL
    type: schema
    objs: public

Comment: This is the user specs from pgadmin: CREATE ROLE sparc2 LOGIN
  NOSUPERUSER INHERIT NOCREATEDB NOCREATEROLE NOREPLICATION;

Answer (score 10, accepted):

PostgreSQL has 2 connection entry points:

1. TCP/IP (`host` in `pg_hba.conf`)
2. Unix sockets (`local` in `pg_hba.conf`)

Your server is configured to use `peer` auth which works only for Unix sockets, and means - ask the kernel if the OS username matches DB username.

You have following options:

- change `pg_hba.conf` to use `md5` auth for `local` socket connections, or
- change connection settings in your script to use IP connection (`127.0.0.1` should work) instead of socket connection. [This may not require editing the files - sometimes setting `PGHOST` variable is enough], or
- make your script to run from OS user `sparc2`, not `postgres`.

---

Risks / drawbacks

- if you change peer to md5, some automation scripts that run from "postgres" OS user, and rely on "peer" auth, will stop working. They will start asking for password
- if you change peer to md5, and forget database superuser password, you may have to re-enable peer auth to reset it.

In general, the "peer" auth is OK. Ease and security of kernel-based local auth is the reason why many distributions choose it for local admin connections. It is useful especially on multi-user shell servers. You can disable it for selected accounts only:

```
#CHANNEL  DB    USER     METHOD
local     all   sparc2   md5
local     all   all      peer
```

More details: [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) and [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/libpq-envars.html).

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot for the answer. The fist option worked. I am not an expert with these customizations. Are there any risks doing this?

Comment: @user1919 the only risk of changing peer to md5: some automation scripts that rely on "peer" auth will stop working. They will start asking for password.